# Troubles with NGINX as reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, pihole

I have a problem configuring an nginx as reverse proxy.
On RaspPI with raspberry Lite OS, I installed the pihole reachable under: 192.168.177.77:81

nginx runs on port 80. In the hosts file on a mac notebook, I created the entry:

192.168.177.77    pihole.dummydomain.com

On the RaspPi, I configured NGINX as reverse proxy:
192.168.177.77:80 should redirects to 192.168.177.77:81

NGINX config:
IN /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/pihole.dummydomain.com.conf

```
server { 
    listen 80;
    server_name pihole.dummydomain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.177.77:81;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```

The redirect does not work. Visting pihole.dummydomain.com shown the nginx default index page instead of the pihole welcome page

Could you please help?

Comment: Why do you need nginX on your Raspberry? Are you planning to have many virtual hosts? If not - then you don't need a reverse proxy, simply expose your app directly.

Comment: I am planning other virtual hosts. This is only a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I did a mistake. I had a former nginx installation and I configured the wrong file.
I removed all nginx installations and install a proper one. Now it works as expected